# Admin rights not working

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this code, it has to filter the rights of admin, I even made a double check. 
But it doesn't seem to work.

**CODE :**

```
<?php
    include("db.php");
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members where admin='true' AND admincheck='1'");
    while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo"<li><a href='archief.php'><span>archief</span></a></li>";
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

**DATABASE :**

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
`member_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
`admin` varchar(5) NOT NULL default 'false',
`admincheck` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
`firstname` varchar(100) default NULL,
`lastname` varchar(100) default NULL,
`mail` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`login` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
`passwd` varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY  (`member_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `members` (`member_id`, `admin`, `admincheck`, `firstname`, `lastname`,   `mail`, `login`, `passwd`) VALUES 
(607, 'true', 1, '---', '----', '---', '---', '---'),
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What does or doesn't it do?

Comment: Your queries work as expected for me, so you must be doing something wrong. Does ``mysql_query`` return some error?

Comment: i cant understand what is problem and what u trying to achieve please be clear so guys can help u.

Comment: It always shows the admin link, while the link has to be hidden for normal users. The problem is, it doesnt hide from Normal users unless I change their value into false and 0. But false and 0 are the standard value's so I have no idea why it doesnt hide.

Comment: There is no *"current user"* in your query. I also hope this is not the only "permission check" you have. You need to be checking on the admin page itself as well.

Comment: instead of checking every user for admin, why not just create a table for admins and give the reference from the user table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the currently logged in member ID into the query, so assuming you store the logged in user in the session:

```
$member_id = (int)$_SESSION['member_id'];
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members where member_id = '$member_id' AND admin='true' AND admincheck='1' LIMIT 1");

if($result && mysql_num_rows($result) == 1)
{
    // user is an admin, show secret links
    echo "<li><a href='archief.php'><span>archief</span></a></li>";
}
```

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem, it's hides the half of the page now.
I changed the session ID because it was **$_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID']** but that didn't work. 

It does hide the link by the way, but also the page and that while I'm admin.

Comment: @DavePiersma I suggest doing the above query and storing a variable to say if the the user an admin, then throughout the page you can refer to that to check if the user is an admin and show special content or not.